# Оранизация передачи данных по Ethernet в Delphi

Tags: ethernet, delphi

Стоит задача: в Delphi передать данные по Ethernet с одного компьютера на другой. Читаю теорию - трудно. 
Помогите на примере. Только программы на обоих компьютерах мои. Поэтому мне нужно помочь и передать и принять данные.
И проще - чтобы МНЕ было понятно.

Comment: http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/sources/internet/1_internet.html и далее по ссылкам. есть соответствующий [исходник](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/sources/internet/2006_year/i_net.html) для вашей задачи.

Comment: Какие данные? Например, MS SQL Server - никаких проблем. Для произвольных бинарных в Delphi7 есть TClientSocket и TServerSocket. Для "текста" выбор больше...

Comment: zevsikk, извините, в конце дня принял Ethernet за Internet, но, в данном случае, это одно и тоже.